# What can I do to execute multiple Singles but only moving to the next when the previous is completed?

Tags: rxjs, rx-java2, system.reactive

I have the next scenario.

**List of Singles**: A, B, C. Each one is a server request and the list size it's not fixed, **it can be any size**.

**My problem**: I need to call A and, when I have the response, then execute B and, when I have the response then execute C... until complete all the calls.

I need something like this: **A Call -> A Response -> B Call -> B response -> C Call -> C Response...**

But using concat I have this: **A Call -> B Call -> C Call -> A response -> B response -> C response...**

So it doesn't work because B Call is exetrancuted before I can get the A response.

I don't know what operator(s) to use to acomplish this. I'm using Java, but this is more a Rx logic/knowledge problem, so any response in another language can be useful too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please provide some code you are trying, but `concatMap` does exactly what you want - waits for previous Observable to complete, before subscribing to next one (and does this in order):

```
of('A', 'B').pipe(
  concatMap(val => Promise.resolve(`${val} Http call`)),
  tap(console.log)
).subscribe(() => console.log('done'))
```

Logs;

```
A Http call
done
B Http call
done
```

Comment: Thank you, I still have some problems (this is part of something more complex) but this is very helpful!